# Android Studio syncs git submodules across projects

Tags: git, android-studio, git-submodules

I have a main project that includes several other GIT projects as submodules. All projects are branched after git-flow. The main project always uses the `master` branch of the submodules. New features within the submodules are developed inside a separate IDE window in the `develop` or `feature` branches.

The problems begin if I open both the main project and a submodule in different windows of AndroidStudio. The IDE seems to recognize that the submodule of the main project's window is the same repository as the module opened in the other window and starts to keep the checked out commit in sync. Example:

1. I open the main project with submodule A checked out on the last commit of `master` branch.
2. I open the module A project in a new IDE window checked out on the last commit of the `develop` branch.
3. I checkout a different commit in the submodule project's window.
4. The submodule within the main project is automatically updated to the commit of step 3. Git shows that the submodule commit has changed.
5. I change the branch of the main project's submodule back to `master`. The git change disappears, but the module A is also checked out on the `master` branch in its own IDE window.

This prevents me from opening both the module and the main project in AndroidStudio simultaneously.

I've checked the following while trying to find the cause of this bug:

- The main project's submodule folder and the folder of the module project are not at the same location.
- Git is not the cause. I've closed the IDE and checked out different commits via the Git-CLI. The commits stay different across both projects.
- Once both projects are open inside AndroidStudio it does not matter how I change the commit (IDE built-in Git-UI, IDE built-in terminal + Git CLI, External terminal + Git CLI). The commits start syncing once I check out a different commit.
- The IDE uses the system's Git binaries.

Is this a bug or a feature? If the latter, is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature, indeed. You can turn it off under Settings | Version Control | Git | [ ] Execute branch operations on all roots (in older versions, this option is called "Control repositories synchronously").

Comment: There is no such option. I am using AndroidStudio 3.0.1. This is its Git settings page: https://i.imgur.com/ohsj5Do.png. Are you using a different version?

Comment: The `Control repositories synchronously` box was never checked in my IDE and it still syncs the commits. Maybe its broken in the current stable version. I will test it with latest canary during the weekend.

Comment: With the release of Android Studio 3.1.1 the solution works as described in the answer.